# how can i fix kernel_regularizer in python 3.6.6

Tags: python, deep-learning

I have problem in Deep Learning .
Didnt work the regularizers say every time not found.
I have tryed to rewrite the text again but i really cant find why this code didnt work.

HERE is all the code of file : https://github.com/shaoanlu/faceswap-GAN/blob/master/FaceSwap_GAN_v2.2_train_test.ipynb

I tryed to import regularizers with another name (as r)
I really dont know why stop only here where run code with same syndax.

```
 def conv_block(input_tensor, f, use_norm=False, strides=2, w_l2=w_l2, 
 norm='none'):
     x = input_tensor
     x = Conv2D(f, kernel_size=3, strides=strides, 
 kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(w_l2),
                kernel_initializer=conv_init, use_bias=False, padding="same") 
 (x)
     x = Activation("relu")(x)
     x = normalization(x, norm, f) if use_norm else x
     return x
```

ERROR

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-76b10e973f9b> in <module>()
----> 1 model = FaceswapGANModel(**arch_config)

2 frames
/content/faceswap-GAN/networks/nn_blocks.py in conv_block(input_tensor, f, use_norm, strides, w_l2, norm)
    126 def conv_block(input_tensor, f, use_norm=False, strides=2, w_l2=w_l2, norm='none'):
    127     x = input_tensor
--> 128     x = Conv2D(f, kernel_size=3, strides=strides, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(w_l2),
    129                kernel_initializer=conv_init, use_bias=False, padding="same")(x)
    130     x = Activation("relu")(x)

NameError: name 'regularizers' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `faceswap-GAN/networks/nn_blocks.py` doesn't import `keras.regularizers`, but uses it. In that file just add, `from keras import regularizers` and it should work.

Also, avoid using older code that is not maintained anymore. A lot has changed in keras and tf since tensorflow 2.0 came out.